# How to enable CSS scroll both X and Y

Tags: html, css

I've searched few hours, but cannot got an answer, So I need some help

There is a div element, provides scroll-x

```
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='el1'></div>
   <div id='el2'></div>
   <div id='el3'></div>
</div>
```

When my mouse cursor locates on that div area, scrolling y does not work

Had tried =>

```
#id overflow: auto
#id overflow-x: auto, overflow-y: auto
#id overflow-x: scroll, overflow-y: scroll
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `overflow-y` or just `overflow: auto`

Comment: @Dai Do you mean `overflow-y` or `overflow:auto` at the parent element? It does not work on mine

Comment: @MinseoLee use `overflow: auto` on the parent `div`.

Comment: @Blaze_droid Does not work same, Sorry

Comment: Your parent needs to have the overflow property, plus you need some height for it in order to work. If the height is smaller than the height of your children combined, then you'll get the scroll

Comment: @MinseoLee you can try `overflow:scroll !important;` as to override some already existing style.

Comment: I have added a working code answer. please have a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this can give you some idea:

```css
#el1, #el2, #el3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  display:inline-block;
}

.parent {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div id='el1'>a</div>
   <div id='el2'>b</div>
   <div id='el3'>c</div>
</div>
```

I this snippet working the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

The key is on setting the `height` and `width` of your parent and children elements.

A horizontal scroll (X-axis) can be achieved if the **total width of the children's elements is bigger than the width of the parent element** plus using `overflow: auto` to the parent element.

A vertical scroll (Y-axis) can be achieved if the **total height of the children's elements is bigger than the height of the parent element** plus using `overflow: auto` to the parent element.

Here is the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-gates-djhnx?file=/src/styles.css

html file:

```js
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
    since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
    essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
    of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
    of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="child-2">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
    since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
    essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
    of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
    of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="child-3">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
    since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
    essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
    of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
    of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

css file:

```css
#parent {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

#child-1 {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#child-2 {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#child-3 {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example on overflow, you have to set `height` and `width` property in `#parent` plus you have to set `overflow` property to auto

if the `width` of any children is greater than parent's width, then it will automatically scroll on x direction

if the total `height` of all children is greater than parent's height, then it will automatically scroll on y direction

```css
#parent{
  background:#333;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
}

#el1{
  background:#999;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}

#el2{
  background:green;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
}

#el3{
  background:yellow;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='el1'></div>
   <div id='el2'></div>
   <div id='el3'></div>
</div>
```